# Detecting internet connection in background in Swift

Tags: reachability, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am performing background tasks connecting to the internet to serve data to a Watch app and I would like to notify it if the paired iPhone is not able to connect to the internet. The reachability class seems not be available on Swift, and anyway I would not know how it would fare in background. On its part:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
    downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
    didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL)
```

has no error parameter, seemingly only returning when some data is available and thereafter leaving everything hanging in the case of an error.

How to I handle this problem?

Comment: For Reachability in Swift try https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Comment: I found that project, but I was looking for something slightly less daunting...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/bobbymay/InternetAvailability

I don't think you can check for Internet while in the background, only when the app comes into the foreground. Check this post out: [How App in background can check for internet connection, IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096314/how-app-in-background-can-check-for-internet-connection-ios)